# What is the necessary lifetime for SetWindowTextA string parameter

Tags: c++, win32gui

I have a program that creates a `std::string s` on the heap and passes it to the `SetWindowTextA(hWnd, s.c_str())`
My question is how long does that string need to live? Does SetWindowTitleA copy the string or do I need to keep the string alive?

Comment: Until the function returns. There is a copy.

Comment: It makes a copy and stores it in the control. And there is no need to create the `std::string` on the heap; it will internally create however large a buffer it needs already in dynamic memory.

Comment: Thanks then my code where I drop the string after calling SetWindowTitleA is not creating a potential npe.

Comment: And yes I didn't actually created a std::string on the heap. I wanted to emphasize that the string is not a constant but will change after the call to SetWindowTitleA returns. Sorry for making that not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my question was answered in the comments here is the the quick answer to anyone having the same question:

Yes SetWindowTitleA will create a copy of the passed in const* char. So the necessary lifetime is until the function returns. Then the passed string can be deleted, dropped or whatever.